# What does ptr sub_xxxxx mean

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

please help me understand what the following assemble code means and does (sorry if it is basic!):

```
mov edx, dword ptr sub_40833C[ecx]
```

Before the operation, ECX is 544h and EDX is 00408887 (address).
The value at address `4083CC` is `55 be d9 b6`.

After the operation the value in EDX is 3A202147.
How does it get this?

Comment: It loads content of memory from `sub_40833C + ecx`. It's irrelevant what's in `edx` or at `sub_40833C` itself (which is code for a function).

Comment: Fantastic, I managed to follow it and verify. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer

Comment: It is the output of a not very good disassembler and is unlikely to be correct.  Good disassemblers cost money.

Answer (score 0):

"It loads content of memory from sub_40833C + ecx. It's irrelevant what's in edx or at sub_40833C itself (which is code for a function)" from Jester